# Inject javascript in webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I have a file with js functions that I need to inject into a webview, but seems I cannot find the right way to do it. As I learned so far I need to inject the js by setting a `setWebViewClient` in the webview and on `onPageFinished` there inject the js by doing this: `webview.loadUrl("javascript:" + js);`
Now my question is this: is the above correct and how can I get the return value of the javascript function that I execute?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> is the above correct

The `loadUrl()` approach is correct for API Level 18 and below. `evaluateJavascript()` was added in API Level 19 as an alternative.

Whether invoking that code in `onPageFinished()` is the right time, we cannot say.

> how can I get the return value of the javascript function that I execute?

Using `loadUrl()`, you don't get the return value, at least not directly. You would have to use `addJavascriptInterface()` on the `WebView`, to register a fake JS global that maps to some Java object that you supply, and have your JavaScript call some method on that global to pass data back out of the `WebView`.

With `evaluateJavascript()`, you can pass in a callback object that will get a `String` representation of whatever the JS returned, if anything.